# CodeIgniter: getting the id of a newly created record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the *CXTags* CI tagging library. The tag_ref table takes a row_id. So my posts can have multiple tags added to them. The method for adding tags takes the table and row_id of the entity being tagged. In my case the table is 'posts' and row_id would be the id of the posts record.

I want to do something like this:

```
$this->db->insert('posts', $_POST);
$this->CXTags->add_tags($data); //where data holds table name and row_id
```

Any help most appreciated!

Billy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$this->db->insert_id()
```

You know the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html) is your friend.